# Can I tile on top of laminate underlay?

Tags: flooring

I have removed the laminate flooring in my hallway and I have left the underlay in place for the time being. I am flowing the tiles from the kitchen into the hallway and the underlay nicely levels the tiles to match. I was wondering if it is possible to keep the underlay down and tile directly on top of it?

Comment: Are you talking about the foam-type underlayment for floating laminate florring? If so, that would definitely be too flexible for tile to go on top of it. Could you clarify the type of underlayment you have, maybe add a picture?

Comment: Yeah it is the foam type. Would that not support tiles then, its a shame because I was hoping it would provide a bit of insulation as well from the concrete

Comment: It would support the tiles but would crack the grout.

Comment: it has got a foil lining on the bottom and doesn't seem to be that flexible.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks, guess I will take it up

Comment: I see that you have a number of unresolved question posts. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what's expected of you when you post a question. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the underlayments I have used for laminate are flexible. With a flexible base your tile will crack and the grout will crumble, not in years time but with each step. So I would say No you can not use this as a base for your tile.

Comment: Unless it's a floating tile, but the OP doesn't specify.